# How to add the Search to CommandBar (MS Fluent UI)?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

How to add a [SearchBox](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/searchbox) to a CommandBar?

I would like to achieve something like this :
[image]

I use [this Fluent UI CommandBar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar)

CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/curtisj44/pen/rNWxPQM)

```
const _items: ICommandBarItemProps[] = [
    {
      key: 'newItem',
      text: 'New',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Add' },
      subMenuProps: {
        items: [
          {
            key: 'emailMessage',
            text: 'Email message',
            iconProps: { iconName: 'Mail' },
            ['data-automation-id']: 'newEmailButton', // optional
          },
          {
            key: 'calendarEvent',
            text: 'Calendar event',
            iconProps: { iconName: 'Calendar' },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      key: 'upload',
      text: 'Upload',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Upload' },
      href: 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui',
    },
    {
      key: 'share',
      text: 'Share',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Share' },
      onClick: () => console.log('Share'),
    },
    {
      key: 'download',
      text: 'Download',
      iconProps: { iconName: 'Download' },
      onClick: () => console.log('Download'),
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is, as usually, missing from [Microsoft docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar), but found on some forums the following

```
const _items: ICommandBarItemProps[] = [
{
   key: "search",
   onRender: () => <SearchBox placeholder="Search" className="searchBox" />
},
```